# Custom style for a Compound Component in Android Library

Tags: android, android-widget, android-library

I would like to know if there is a way to specify and style for an Android compound control (widget) in a library.

We have moved our compound controls in a library to be reusables, but we don't know how to specify a custom style when we use them in a activity from android app project.

We have found this [helpful blog](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2011/03/custom-styles-in-android-libraries.html), to do something similar but It has to specify the custom style as application theme, and we would like to apply one style directly to the compound component.

I have tryed with something like this but the application crashes.

```
<MyLibraryNameSpace.MyCompoundComponent ...... style="@style/StyleForMyCompoundComponent">
```

Comment: No, at least two years ago when I needed it, I didn't find solution to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll keep this post in mind if/when I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply styles just like you can do to any other view, just like you are showing in your question. Possibly the reason for the crash was a different one. Remember that the elements of your compound controls do not apply the style specified to the control itself by default. For example, if you if you create a compound control with a FrameLayout holding a Button and an EditText, setting the background of your compound control will attempt to be applied to the FrameLayout (the parent holder of your control), and not the elements inside of it (Button and EditText) unless you determine that explicitly.

If you want to add custom methods for your component you can do so in your `attrs.xml`. Suppose for example that you wanted to expose a property to modify the aspect ratio of your component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
...

    <declare-styleable name="MyCompoundComponent">
        <attr name="aspectRatio" format="float"/>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Then in the constructor of your custom control you can get the value of these custom props:

```
...
public MyCompoundComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    if (attrs == null) return;

    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCompoundComponent, defStyleAttr, 0);
    this.aspectRatio = typedArray.getFloat(R.styleable.MyCompoundComponent_aspectRatio, 1);
}
```

Once there, you can simply use the value for the collected properties whenever convenient.